# Duplicate question from other SE sites

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

Are duplicate question from other SE sites allowed to be posted? I would guess that they would not be as the question should be posted in the appropriate SE site and not on multiples to gain more view/answers for a given question.

If these questions are not allowed what should they be flagged as? I was going to flag a particular question as duplicate but it informed me that "The duplicate question must exist on Webmasters Stack Exchange".

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92051/getting-a-javascript-dom-event-for-end-of-display) on ProWebmasters is an exact copy of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436423/getting-a-javascript-dom-event-for-end-of-display) on StackOverflow (with the exception of the extra line of text explaining that it is an exact copy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Is SO/SE crosspost accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255649/is-so-se-crosspost-accepted):

Posting the same question on two (or more sites) simultaneously is, while not strictly disallowed, somewhat counter productive. It's a rare question that's on topic on multiple sites. In this case one of the questions should be closed or possibly migrated and merged if it has answers.

Where is the question most on-topic? If you can answer that, flag the post on the other site with the "other" option indicating it's been cross posted and include the link. A moderator can review and migrate if they agree. They can also liaise with the mods on the other site to make sure it gets quickly merged or migrated the other way if necessary.

Here's what I said on [Programmer's meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6668/47) when the more general topic came up:

> Reasking the question so **that it's tailored to the other site's audience** is OK. You'll bring out aspects that the first site missed or you'll be able to focus your question as a result of the answers on the first site.
>
> Just copy/pasting the question from one site to another isn't going to work well. It's either going to be totally off message (note not necessarily off topic, but just not "right" for the site) for one site or the other or worse, fall between the two sites and be a bad question on both.
>
> The thing to to do is think about the target audience of the site and think about what sort of answers you want to get.